# How to Access Cells of Excel using Winium?

Tags: excel, automated-tests, winium

I have created one software in excel. I am writing test cases for testing purpose of that software.

While automating test cases I am able to click on Menu Tabs of excel. But if I want to paste data in cell of a sheet or want to enter data in a cell I am not able to click on any cell using winium.

Also I try to inspect using inspect.exe and UISpy.exe but not able to get "Automation Id" or "Name" for cells.

Is there any way to paste Data or Enter Data in cells of Excel sheet ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First of all, what does `I have created one software in excel` mean? VBA? ActiveX? Something else? Same for `click on Menu Tabs` - do you mean `ribbon`? Or maybe you use Excel pre-2007?